# How to tap all items of a list or a grid in a Flutter widget test?

Tags: flutter, testing, widget-test-flutter

In my Flutter widget tests I want to tap all (or first n) items in a list or grid view.

I already came up with a solution and although it seems to work, it looks overly complicated to find the tap target again by key:

```dart
for (final element in find.byType(ListTile).evaluate()) {
  await tester.tap(find.byKey(element.widget.key!));
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can tap at a certain location on the widget:
e.g. tapping at center of the widget

```dart
for (final element in find.byType(ListTile).evaluate()) {
  await tester.tapAt(tester.getCenter(find.byWidget(element.widget)));
}
```